# Why can we ignore the weak conjugate base/acid when calculating the pH in a titration problem?

Tags: ph, titration

Take the reaction 350 mL of 0.8M HCN and 0.6M NaOH for example. The problem asks us the calculate the pH when we add 500 mL of 0.6M NaOH into the 350 mL of 0.8M HCN (This is more than enough to neutralize the weak acid). However, the problem states that we can ignore OH contributions from water or any weak base. Can someone explain why we can do this?

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) type of question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this. Good luck.

Comment: @airhuff I mean I did to the rest of the problem (ie solving the pH) but that little statement still stumped me.  If this still violates the policy then I'll gladly shut this down myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{NaOH}$ is a strong base. It is assumed that it **dissociates completely** in aqueous solutions, hence, it's contribution to the $\ce{OH-}$ concentration is the *maximum* as compared to other weak bases or water. Moreover, due to common ion effect, the presence of $\ce{OH-}$ ions in solution due to $\ce{NaOH}$ further hinders the dissociation of the *already* weak bases, thereby making their contributions negligible.